# how to add to a dictionary value or create if not exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add to a value in a dictionary storing counters:

```
d[key] += 1
```

but sometimes the key will not exist yet. Checking to see if the key exists seems too ugly. Is there a nice and pythonic one liner for this - add if the key exists, or create the value `1` if the key is not in the dict.keys ?

thanks

Comment: You have several options - [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), `try: except KeyError:`, [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe depending on behaviour, also `collections.Counter`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` - this guarantees that all values are `1` or more, supports various ways of initialisation, and supports certain other useful abilities that a `dict`/`defaultdict` don't:

```
from collections import Counter

values = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']

# Take an iterable and automatically produce key/value count
counts = Counter(values)
# Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
print counts['a'] # 2
print counts['d'] # 0
# Note that `counts` doesn't have `0` as an entry value like a `defaultdict` would
# a `dict` would cause a `KeyError` exception
# Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})

# Manually update if finer control is required
counts = Counter()
for value in values:
    counts.update(value) # or use counts[value] += 1
# Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Comment: but later stage he got new element into the list so again has to follow one of the answer below right?

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: @sundar you'd just `.update` the original `counts` as shown in the second example...

Comment: That second example solves all issues.  What a wonderful little add-on this is.

Answer (score 19):

you can use

```
d={}
key='sundar'

d[key]=d.get(key,0)+1
print d
#output {'sundar': 1}
d[key]=d.get(key,0)+1
print d
#output {'sundar': 2}
```

Comment: @WeaselFox In fact I like it, I wish it would be mandatory to add a comment to each down vote.

Comment: @WeaselFox who know there should be restriction if they downvoted they need to comment then only it became valid downvote:(

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> key = 'foo'
>>> d[key] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'foo': 1})
>>> d[key]
1
>>> d[key] += 1
>>> d[key]
2
```

Comment: nice. I knew there had to be a nicer way.

Comment: @WeaselFox just be careful to perform an operation... `defaultdict` triggers the `__default__` behaviour on a `__getitem__`, so if you just did `foo[key]` where it didn't exist, you'll get an entry of `key: 0` in your counter

Answer (score 3):

`collections.Counter` is the best for the specific use case you gave, but for a more general solution that doesn't require importing anything, use `dict.setdefault()`:

```py
d[key] = d.setdefault(key, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Note to viewers: with this syntax, the second argument of setdefault should not be the default value, but the default value minus 1. That is because the +1 at the end will always add 1 to it.